# sending two arrays to PHP in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have two arrays and I need to send the array values to PHP. When I print the value that returns from PHP,  it prints an empty string. How can I get it? my code is below.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test2.php",
    data: {
        price: [101, 69, 51],
        id: [1, 2, 3]
    },
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
    }
})​;​
```

In PHP

```
  $id=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id'][0]);        
  echo $id;
```

Comment: You should probably accept some answers first.

Comment: How can I do it? I a new here.

Comment: You need to go back to all the other questions you asked and click the outline of the checkmark next to the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `var_dump($_POST)`. That way you can see exactly what the structure of the array is, so you know how to access it.